# Python - Not recognizing Exception Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am having problems with exception handling, I am running Python 3.6.3. 
this is my code:

```
txt = ""
txtFile = input("gimme a file.")
f = open(txtFile, "r")
try:    
    for line in f:
        cleanedLine = line.strip() 
        txt += cleanedLine
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("!")
```

So if I try and get an error with a bad input
Instead of printing `!` I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cleaner.py", line 11, in <module>
    f = open(txtFile, "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nonexistentfile'
```

I have tried swapping in `OSError`, I have also tried just `except:`, which tells me that I am doing something wrong(because I shouldn't do that in the first place) and since I understand that `except:` should catch all of the exceptions.

Comment: The error occurs before your try statement. Hence the error will not be caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you're opening something outside of the exception.

```
txt = []
txtFile = input("gimme a file.")
try:        
    f = open(txtFile, "r")
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        cleanedLine = line.strip()
        txt.append(cleanedLine)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try catch is encapsulating the loop through the lines.

The error is occurring when you are trying to open the file, outside of your try block.

Comment: thanks, I am new to this, and I was misinterpreting the traceback .